# Request.Form vs. IFormCollection in MVC Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My MVC project has a view that lets a user enter data into a textbox, submit the form and have the controller search the database for that string and then render the results into the view.  I have it working 2 different ways, via Request.Form and IFormCollection.  They both seem to work.  What's the difference and which should I use?

I've attached the view page and the controller code.

```
@model List<AirSicknessBags.Models.Bagsmvc>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Bags";
}
 
<h1>Bag List</h1>
 
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Bags", FormMethod.Post))
 
{
    <h2>Find Airline</h2>
    <input type="text" id="Airline" name="Airline" />
    <input type="submit" />
}
 
@*Display the data returned*@
@if (Model != null)
{
    @foreach (var x in Model)
    {
        <h3>@x.Airline</h3>
        <h4>@Html.Raw(x.Detail)</h4>
    }
}
```

Here's the controller snippet.  Both airline and airline2 work fine.

```
        // Post: Bags
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(IFormCollection collection)
        {
            string airline = Request.Form["Airline"].ToString();
            string airline2 = collection["Airline"].ToString();
            IActionResult bags = await GetAllFromDatabase(airline);

            var okResult = bags as OkObjectResult;
            var baglist = okResult.Value as List<Bagsmvc>;

            return View(baglist);
        }
```

Comment: You already receive the form as a parameter and better yet, in its abstract form. What you actually receive is the class [FormCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.formcollection?view=aspnetcore-3.1) which has everything you need. Using Request will increase your method's [Class Coupling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/code-metrics-values?view=vs-2019) metric. That's one reason why to avoid it. The second reason is added complexity to testability. If you choose Request, it needs to be mocked

Comment: better way would be to return strongly typed model which you already use in form